# point cloud height problem

Tags: ros, laser-pipeline

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

We are using pr2_laser_snapshotter with laser_scan_assembler to get point cloud from our tilt laser. We noticed an offset in the z direction of the /base_link when the torso is not fully raised.
[image: image description]

Unlike the point cloud in the picture above that is shifted up, the point cloud in the picture below is at the right height. The blue horizontal line is drawn in the /base_footprint frame as a reference.

[image: image description]

Below is the launch file we used to get the point cloud:

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="pr2_mechanism_controllers" type="send_periodic_cmd_srv.py"
        name="laser_cmd"
    args="laser_tilt_controller linear 10 1 .35" />

  <node type="laser_scan_assembler" pkg="laser_assembler"
    name="tilt_scan_assembler">
    <remap from="scan" to="tilt_scan"/>
    <param name="max_scans" type="int" value="400" />
    <param name="fixed_frame" type="string" value="base_link" />
    <param name="ignore_laser_skew" type="bool" value="true" />
  </node>

  <node pkg="pr2_laser_snapshotter" type="pr2_laser_snapshotter" output="screen\
"
        name="snapshotter">
    <remap from="laser_scanner_signal"
           to="/laser_tilt_controller/laser_scanner_signal"/>
    <remap from="full_cloud" to="tilt_laser_cloud" />
  </node>
</launch>
```

Thanks for your help!

Huan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10754/point-cloud-height-problem/) by [liuhuanjim013](https://answers.ros.org/users/446/liuhuanjim013/) on ROS Answers with karma: 152 on 2011-07-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Changing the mechanical reduction of the torso is only going to mask other problems. The mechanical reduction numbers for your robot will never change, even after calibration. Recalibrating the robot only changes the offsets of each joint.

Thank you for bringing this to my attention. I'm going to investigate this value and make sure the mechanical reduction is correct for the PR2 torso.

---

Originally posted by [watts](https://answers.ros.org/users/99/watts/) with karma: 584 on 2011-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TomTUM](https://answers.ros.org/users/547/tomtum/) on 2011-07-29**:
Kevin, check Request #616 on support. For us, it solved the issue. I would also expect other robots to have the same issue, would be great to have checked official values :)

**Comment by [liuhuanjim013](https://answers.ros.org/users/446/liuhuanjim013/) on 2011-07-28**:
Hi Kevin, Thanks for the reply! What do you recommend us to do now? Shall I play with the mechanicalReduction value at all?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For the TUM PR2, we had a similar issue, it turned out to be a calibration problem of the spine.
I adjusted the urdf file in /etc/ros/distro/urdf/robot.xml to compensate for the error, it works fine now. Looks like this for us:

`'<transmission name="torso_lift_trans" type="pr2_mechanism_model/SimpleTransmission"> '<actuator name="torso_lift_motor"/> '<joint name="torso_lift_joint"/> '<!--mechanicalReduction>-52143.33</mechanicalReduction--> '<mechanicalReduction>-47532.66</mechanicalReduction> '</transmission>`

So i measured maximum and minimum encoder value via 'rostopic echo /motor_trace/torso_lift_motor' along with actual positions. You can then guess what the actual mechanicalReduction should be.

---

Originally posted by [TomTUM](https://answers.ros.org/users/547/tomtum/) with karma: 481 on 2011-07-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [liuhuanjim013](https://answers.ros.org/users/446/liuhuanjim013/) on 2011-07-28**:
Hi Tom, Thanks a lot! I followed your advice and noticed a few things: when I move the torso to its limits, the encoder position I get is the same constant no matter where the torso is. When I look at the encoder count in pr2_dashboard, they read -68456 and 2804881. How do I get mechanicalReduction?